# "Column '' does not exist" error with no column name

Tags: sharepoint

When creating or editing list item in SharePoint 2013, I am getting the somewhat common error that says, **"Column '' does not exist.It may have been deleted by another user."**
 The problem is that there is no column name listed in the quotes. It is blank. I have run a powershell script to output all the fields on the lists and there doesn't appear to be any issues there. A few columns are using managed metadata. But I can't think of a solution or reason as to why this happened in the first place.

Comment: Check your forms in SPD for columns that do not exist in the list definition

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've compared forms on lists that work to those that don't, and there's no contributing difference between the forms.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when i was deleting the specific list item programatically.

I observed that the item deleting event was firing in backend.

I solved this problem by creating two methods for disabling & enabling the events at in event receiver and created the object of event receiver class and called these methods before deleting the item programatically.